# How can I remove rows containing '0' of certain columns while keeping the rows IDs of remaining rows in R

Tags: r

I am trying to sort it out but could not able to do it. I want to get rid of all the rows with '0' values but keeping the ID numbers intact of remaining rows.

```
ID  B   C   D
1_2 34  42  12
1_3 34  32  2
1_4 0   0   0
1_5 12  33  12
```

output should be

```
ID  B   C   D
1_2 34  42  12
1_3 34  32  2
1_5 12  33  12
```

Comment: Is the `ID` a row name or a column in your data frame?

Comment: Do you want to remove the rows if all three columns B, C, and D are 0 or if at least one of them is 0?

Comment: dplyr solution please, **filter(function(z) any(z != 0), - ID)** ? doesn't work ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if you want to remove the lines containing a 0 or many for column B,C or D :

```
DF[apply(DF[c(2:4)],1,function(z) !any(z==0)),]
```

or only when  all columns B,C,D contains 0 :

```
DF[apply(DF[c(2:4)],1,function(z) any(z!=0)),]
```

Comment: I have a very basic question, but what does the 1 stand for?

Comment: @Danka- 1 stands for row. If you replace it with 2, the command will work on the columns.

Comment: Shouldn't this be `DF[apply(DF[, c(2:4)],1,function(z) any(z!=0))]`

Comment: I have df2= df1[apply(df1[c(3:100)],1,function(z) !any(z==0)),] and it doesn't remove rows that contain 0 from column3 to column100. If there any comments?

Answer (score 1):

If tmp is the name of your original data.frame, the following works:

```
tmp2 <- data.frame(Reduce(rbind,apply(tmp,1,function(x){if(any(x==0)){NULL}else{x}})))
```